# How to get dictionary variable within an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm writing a pokemon like turn base battle simulator. I have gotten pretty far so well but I'm having a problem. I'm trying to write the moves as a dictionary so that I can then specify the move set for every monster in it's object. This way I have 1 dictionary holding all the moves and damage they do. Then I just pass those moves to the monsters which are the objects. This allows me to give each monster unique movesets and not have to specify the damage each move does everytime. The problem I'm having is in the while loop when the user picks the attack I'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm trying to get the attack the user inputs so that it grabs the damage and subtracts it from monster1hp

If I put the dictionary in the object it works fine but then every object has to have it's own dictionary I want to just have 1 dictionary for all moves and then specify the moves for each object in it's move set, if that makes sense.

```
import random

class Monster:
  def __init__(self, name, types, hp, region, disc, strength, weakness, moveset):
    self.name = name
    self.type = types
    self.hp = hp
    self.region = region
    self.disc = disc
    self.strength = strength
    self.weakness = weakness
    self.moveset = moveset

moves_dict = {
    "hyperbeam": 14, 
    "flames": 34,
    "water": 27,
    "cent": 33,
    }


Ariol = Monster("Ariol", "shadow", 1000, "Xevor", "A monster from hell", "psychic", "electricity", {"hyperbeam", "flames", "water", "cent"})
Xenos = Monster("Xenos", "shadow", 300, "Xevor", "A monster from hell", "psychic", "electricity", {"hyperbeam", "flames", "water", "cent"})
Siance = Monster("Siance", "shadow", 500, "Xevor", "A monster from hell", "psychic", "electricity", {"hyperbeam", "flames", "water", "cent"})
Mammy = Monster("Mammy", "shadow", 3000, "Xevor", "A monster from hell", "psychic", "electricity", {"hyperbeam", "flames", "water", "cent"})

def choose_monster():

    monster_menu = {
    "Ariol" : Ariol,
    "Xenos" : Xenos,
    "Siance" : Siance,
    "Mammy" : Mammy,

    }

    #choosemonster
    trainer_monster = input("What monster do you want to use?\n")
    #variable is holding monster chosen
    monster_chosen1 = monster_menu.get(trainer_monster)
    #get monster 1 hp
    computer_choose = random.choice(list(monster_menu))
    computer_chosen1 = monster_menu[computer_choose]
    print("You chose", monster_chosen1.name,"!")
    print("Your opponenet chose", computer_chosen1.name, "!")

    #this dict not used
    moveset_dict = {
    "1": 14, 
    "2": 34,
    "3": 27,
    "4": 33,
    }

    #how to get monster hp from above
    #monster1hp = Ariol.hp
    monster1hp = monster_chosen1.hp
    monster2hp = computer_chosen1.hp

    while monster1hp or monster2hp <= 0:
            #monster1 moveset
            for x in monster_chosen1.moveset:
                print(x)
            choose_attack = input("What move would you like to use?\n")
            attack_chosen = monster_chosen1.moveset.get(choose_attack)
            monster2hp = monster2hp - attack_chosen
            print(monster_chosen1.name, "used ", attack_chosen, computer_chosen1.name, "has", monster2hp, "hp")
            if monster2hp <= 0:
                print(computer_chosen1.name, "was knocked out", monster_chosen1.name, "wins!")
                break
            attack_chosen = random.choice(list(computer_chosen1.moveset))
            monster1hp -= computer_chosen1.moveset[attack_chosen]
            print(computer_chosen1.name, "used", attack_chosen, monster_chosen1.name, "has", monster1hp, "hp")
            if monster1hp <= 0:
                print(monster_chosen1.name, "was knocked out", computer_chosen1.name, "wins!")
                break

    else:
        print("Battle over")


choose_monster()
```

Comment: For one, the user types in the name of the attack, so you don't actually need to retrieve it from the set, you can use `choose_attack` directly

Comment: Second, and this is not related to your original question, but you're making the user input a string, so their input is subject to typos. If you make `moveset` a dictionary, such as `{1: "hyperbeam", 2: "flames", 3: "water", 4: "cent"}`, the user could just type in a number, which is much more limited choice. Then your code would work

Comment: @Arseny it won't work at all. Of course he won't get the get error but he would get another error because he tries to subtract a string from an integer. And of course choosing integer as key may reduce the chance of a typo but is it really fun to play a game in which you have to type numbers? and even if you change it you still have to check of correct inputs. What do you do when the user puts -1? so not a lot changed. It is his style to choose string and that is fine in my eyes. He wants to get the dmg value of a dict defined in the beginning so he still has to that lookup.

Comment: @Boendal, that's a different matter. He has a dictionary for that, too, he's just not using it.

Comment: @Boendal, I'm assuming the user is playing the game for fun, not to break the game. Yes, ideally you'd want to check for input errors regardless, and handle them when they occur. And if someone has genuine difficulties typing long words correctly, it'll be much more frustrating getting the same error feedback over and over even if the input is pretty close to intended

Comment: @Arseny sure you have a valid point but that is purely a matter of taste so not relevant for this question. But what I didn't like was your comment about it would fix his problem: It would only create other trouble so it won't fix anything.

Comment: @Boendal, I didn't mean to rewrite the game, and I didn't post it as an answer, more like a mere observation. I think it was a good point to start, but there might be more issues than just that one. Anyhow, the question was about the set specifically.

Comment: yeah i agree but I'm going to port it to Swift and have the user touch the option this is just to sketch the game out for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line (I take only one monster as example)

```
Ariol = Monster("Ariol", "shadow", 1000, "Xevor", "A monster from hell", "psychic", "electricity", {"hyperbeam", "flames", "water", "cent"})
```

In here you define his attacks as a set of options. And a set doesn't have a get method.

So you have to take your dmg value from moves_dict:

```
choose_attack = input("What move would you like to use?\n")
while not choose_attack in monster_chosen1.moveset: #check if the move is in the moveset
    choose_attack = input("Invalid Move\n") # if not in the moveset try again
attack_chosen = moves_dict.get(choose_attack) # take the dmg value from the moves_dict which has a get method.
```

of course if you want to have different dmg value for each monster, you can replace that set with a dict and in this way you can play around with the dmg value with would make the moves_dict obsolet.

A similar change has to do with the attack the computer choose. But because he always choose valid moves he doesn't need a while loop of course. But the dmg value has to be taken from the moves_dict.

```
monster1hp -= moves_dict[attack_chosen]
```

Comment: great idea but for the computer to auto attack might run into some problems because if the computer choose an invalid attack it might take forever to choose a valid one

Comment: the computer will never choose an invalid attack because he use the moveset you defined for the Monster.. Humans are error prone if they make a typo or something. I added it into my answer, that the computer doesn't need a while loop.

Comment: gotcha! So what should I change for the computer code? I'm looking at it right now thank u so much as well this is helping me so much

Comment: Only the line I posted nothing else needs a rework. Maybe change some variable names and modify your print outputs because they are a bit wrong sometimes for example: attack_chosen  => dmg_value (because it's a number) and it's not really a good coding style to have 2 variables with switched names. it's a bit confusing. And choose_attack is something you do so I thought first it's a function, but it's a state so "chosen_attack" would fit more.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the last paragraph of your question:

You can set up a dictionary in your class without using self and when you update it for one of the objects it will also update it for all of the other objects. This is called a Class Variable.

Here is an example that I coded up to show you what I mean:

```
class testGlobal:
    def __init__(self):
        here_for_no_real_reason = True

    testDict = {'hello': 'hello', 'goodbye': 'goodbye'}


def driver():
    obj1 = testGlobal()
    obj2 = testGlobal()

    print(obj1.testDict)
    print(obj2.testDict)

    obj1.testDict["I'm new"] = "I'm new"
    obj2.testDict['hello'] = "goodbye"

    print(obj1.testDict)
    print(obj2.testDict)


driver()
```

Output:

```
{'hello': 'hello', 'goodbye': 'goodbye'}
{'hello': 'hello', 'goodbye': 'goodbye'}
{'hello': 'goodbye', 'goodbye': 'goodbye', "I'm new": "I'm new"}
{'hello': 'goodbye', 'goodbye': 'goodbye', "I'm new": "I'm new"}
```

From this output you can see that when you change something in the dictionary using obj1 it also changes it for obj2 and vice versa. Hope this helps!

*If you have any further questions let me know I'm happy to try and help*